# command executed in nohup is killed as soon as the putty terminal is closed

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, putty, ubuntu-12.04, amazon-ec2, mysqldump

I have an Amazon ubuntu ec2 instance

I'm using PuTTY to access the same.

Here, I have a large database in mysql. I'm executing the following command to take the backup of my database.

nohup mysqldump -u username -ppassword mydatabase | gzip > mydatabase.sql.gz

Now, when I exit PuTTY, the command is no longer running in the background.

I also tried running with &

i.e nohup mysqldump -u username -ppassword mydatabase | gzip > mydatabase.sql.gz &

All these days it was working fine. But, all of a sudden it is behaving strangely.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Write everything besides `nohup` and `&` in a script and invoke the script with `nohup` and `&`. Maybe gzip is terminating when you close the Putty. If wrting full command in the script will fail - let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments to `nohup` terminate before the pipe symbol, because the shell interprets metachars like `|` and `>` before the command is invoked.

The command line provided will direct the standard output of nohup (not `mysqldump`) to the standard input of `gzip`. So when you log out, your shell and any child processes receive a hangup signal. `nohup` will prevent the signal from reaching the `mysqldump` command, but the `gzip` command will be killed because it is still attached to the controlling terminal which is being closed as you exit your session.

You can put your command in a script as mnmnc suggests, or invoke a new shell to run the entire pipeline:

`nohup sh -c 'mysqldump -u user -ppass db | gzip > db.sql.gz' &`

Here `nohup` will call a single command, `sh`. Note its standard output will be directed to the file `nohup.out` by default, but we don't expect any output from this command since we redirect the standard output of `mysqldump`.

The newly-spawned shell will invoke the command pipeline `mysqldump | gzip`, redirecting the standard output of `gzip` to the specified file.

Here you can see the difference in the commands invoked (using `dd` instead of `mysqldump` for these examples):

```
$ nohup dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M count=50 | gzip > /tmp/out.gz &
[1] 10721
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout

$ jobs
[1]  10720 Running                 nohup dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M count=50
     10721                       | gzip > /tmp/out.gz &
```

vs.

```
$ nohup sh -c 'dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M count=50 | gzip > /tmp/out.gz' &
[1] 10792
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’

$ jobs
[1]  10792 Running                 nohup sh -c 'dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M count=50 | gzip > /tmp/out.gz' &
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Zack.The shell scripting works.Any idea as to why my script (with out adding shell) was working earlier and all of a sudden it is failing. 
Anyways, thanks a lot for your solution :)

Comment: One possibility is that the database is growing over time and at first, the `mysqldump | gzip` pipeline finished before you exited the shell. Later, the command was still running when you exited, which would cause `gzip` to be killed and `mysqldump` to receive a `SIGPIPE`.